# Populate a div with ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a div with the content of an Ajax response.

On the line marked "POPULATION LINE" I have tried:

```
$("#time").val(result[0]);
$("#time").html(result[0]);
$("#time").innerHTML(result[0]);
$("#time").html(result['Time']);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

My div:

```
<div class="fixed" id="time"></div>
<div class="fixed" id="operator"></div>
<div class="fixed" id="destination"></div>
<div class="fixed" id="platform"></div>
<div class="fixed" id="estimated"></div>
```

My Ajax response:

```
 0: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Ayr", Platform: null, Estimated: "On time"}
1: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Dalmuir", Platform: "17", Estimated: "On time"}
2: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Whifflet", Platform: "16", Estimated: "On time"}
3: {Time: "15:05", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Neilston", Platform: null, Estimated: "On time"}
```

My Jquery

```
success: function(data){
    var result = JSON.stringify(data); 
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log("RESULT", result);
    $("#time").html(result['Time']); //POPULATION LINE
```

Console.log

```
0: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Ayr", Platform: null, Estimated: "On time"}
1: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Dalmuir", Platform: "17", Estimated: "On time"}
2: {Time: "15:04", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Whifflet", Platform: "16", Estimated: "On time"}
3: {Time: "15:05", Operator: "ScotRail", Destination: "Neilston", Platform: null, Estimated: "On time"}
```

Comment: what exactly are you getting in data? Not content itself, but type and data? And why are you first using JSON.stringify and then back with JSON.parse?

Comment: Hi, well the script that performs the ajax returns as "json_encode($data);"

Comment: I believe then only thing you need is `result = JSON.parse(data);` and `$("#time").html(result['Time']);` should work.

Comment: If `result` is `{Time: "14:40"}` as you claim then [what you have now works](https://jsfiddle.net/o7muLbg5/).  Can you provide an example demonstrating the problem?  In the example you can simply hard-code the actual response from the server instead of using AJAX, focusing on the specific problem being described.

Comment: result = JSON.parse(data); produces an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Jason returns data likeL 0:
Destination: "Ayr"
Estimated: "On time"
Operator: "ScotRail"
Platform: null
Time: "15:04"

Comment: please console.log(data) and post exactly what you get, not "data like"

Comment: U have put the console,log content in the question

Comment: @DCJones: The data originally shown in the question, the error message indicated in a comment above, the data shown in a comment above, and the data now shown in the question are all very different from one another.  We can't know which one is right if you're changing the structure every time.  Please take a few moments to update the question with a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @David I have added the complete DIV structure along with the complete Ajax response. I hope that help I was tiring to keep the question short, sorry.

Comment: @DCJones: If that's the case then the response from the server is *not* JSON.  It's a custom data format that is *similar* to JSON but you'll have to parse it manually.  (Alternatively, it's possible that you *are* getting valid JSON from the server and are providing us incorrect information in the question, in which case there wouldn't be much we could do to help.)  Once again, a [mcve] which actually demonstrates the problem would be the most effective way to get help here.

Comment: @David point yaken. I will ask the question again providing more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your results looks like an array, if I understood the console output. please try:

```js
$("#time").html(result[0].Time);
```